# Play Framework Packaging Source Files

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

is there a way to package JUST my source code (into jars or class files) and then run that using play framework?  I don't want to use play dist since it packages play itself, which has dependencies on a couple jars that have GPL licenses.

Something like

play package -> I get jar file of just my source code
install play on another computer
play package run -> runs the source code jar files

Answer (score 0):

There is a task in sbt called `packageSrc` that will prepare a jar with the sources, like the ones published along the main jar in maven and ivy, maybe that will do the trick?